# How to move clips without loosing transitions?

Tags: premiere, transitions

Any transition disappears when one of the two joined clips are moved in the timeline.

In Vegas you can reposition clips without loosing the transitions. Can this be done in Premiere as well?

Answer (score 2):

The "Slide Tool" tool makes it possible to move a single clip without loosing the transition connected to another clip.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can move two clips simultaneously, and then the transition between them will stay. If you move only one clip, how program shall understand, which clip shall keep the transition? And what kind of behavior we need to expect, if new place of the clip will not have any other clip next to it?

You can choose one transition, and remake it anywhere in your composition with shortcuts.